# Xamarin.Forms How to remove a single line from the list after id?

Tags: asp.net-core, webapi

Sorry for my english. I added a single line delete event from listview

```
                var button = sender as Image;
                var training = button.BindingContext as TDiary;
               
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
               
                var result = await client.DeleteAsync("Uri/api/training/" + $"{training.Id}");
```

My removal webapi is as follows:

```
  [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {

        var training = context.Trainings
                   .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);

        //czy zasob istnieje
        if (training == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        context.Remove(training);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return NoContent();
    }
```

In TDiary class I keep training Id.
I don't know why, but I can't delete any lines.

Comment: are you asking how to remove it **from the ListView** after you delete it from your service?

Comment: I would like to delete a row in the database

Comment: then this really has nothing to do with Xamarin.  If you're using Entity Framework, you should add that tag too

Comment: @ReVoPEP Hi, which type of database you used in project?

Comment: relational database ms sql